# Cannot use UsageStatsManager or UsageStats in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

When using UsageStatsManager or UsageStats in Android Studio, it says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'UsageStatsManager' / 'UsageStats'

I have downloaded SDK Platform, Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google APIs and Sources for Android SDK under **Android 5.0.1 (API 21)** from Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `buildSdkVersion` to 21 or higher in your `build.gradle` file. [`UsageStatsManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) was added in API Level 21; you need to be compiling against API Level 21 to reference that class.

Comment: Actually I have imported my project to Android Studio from Eclipse and forgot to change it to a Gradle project. So, it doesn't have a `build.gradle` file. However setting `targetSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to 21 doesn't help. What can be done on this?

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any method to get app statistics in previous apis?